# Is it bad practice to duplicate data across different flux stores?

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Say you want each feature to have it's own store for modularity, but multiple features may need the same data x. Is it bad practice to hold x in Feature1Store, Feature2Store, etc?

Comment: I usually make some sort of service or common store that handles data duplication, but it really depends on what are you trying to get. Duplicate data is not *always* bad.

Comment: Is the data constant? Does it need to be in sync in all the stores?

Comment: @abhishek the data does not need to in sync across the stores because each feature doesn't care about other stores. at the same time however, i don't expect the stores to change the data so the data will be constant even though it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if the store represents the state of the data. No if the store represents the state of the component. A well excepted rule about data is that you only want one instance of that data. Otherwise you will have consistency issues. But if the data is not changing and you only are providing sorting, filtering or some other component level state multiple instances are ok.